# How to pass variable to the Flask function while using threading?

Tags: python, flask, python-multithreading

I want to create multiple threads and every one of them should create flask app.
I am not sure how to do it, but that's what I have:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.url_map.strict_slashes = False

@app.route('/api/v1/something/<string:FirstArgument>/<string:SecondArgument>/', methods=['POST'])
def do_it(FirstArgument, SecondArgument):
request_str = request.get_data().decode('utf-8').strip()
response = somefunction(mydata.state, request_str)
return response, 200

def run_app(this_port, mydata):
    currentThread = threading.current_thread()    
    mydata.state = some_function_that_returns_6GB_of_data()    
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=this_port)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mydata = threading.local()
    thread1 = Thread(target=run_app, args=(4100, mydata,))
    #thread2 = Thread(target=run_app, args=(4101,mydata,))
    thread1.start()
    #thread2.start()
```

For now I want to test only one thread. And I don't know how to pass mydata.state to the 'do_it'. If I add new argument (def do_it(FirstArgument, SecondArgument, mydata.state)) than Flask says that he wants to get this variable from the app.route. How can I pass this data to the do_it function?

And one more question. This program will pas N instances of state to N threads on N ports?
Or I should do something like this:

```
def do_it(FirstArgument, SecondArgument):
    request_str = request.get_data().decode('utf-8').strip()
    response = somefunction(mydata.state[threading.get_ident()], request_str)
    return response, 200

def run_app(this_port, mydata):
    currentThread = threading.current_thread()
    mydata.state[threading.get_ident()] = some_function_that_returns_6GB_of_data()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=this_port)
```

Comment: and how are you going to manage the port in which so many threaded application will work?

Comment: I use nginx. Pretty easy - it can manage load.

Comment: Also, I managed to complete the task. It was much easier to make a python script with Flask for only one port and call this script from another python script N times with number of port as an argument.